# How to find zipalign for aligning an android apk

Tags: android-sdk-tools

I downloaded the stand-alone sdk tools on my linux station, but I cannot run `zipalign`. When I attempt to do so I get an error saying that no such command exists. What is the proper way to install and access `zipalign` on a ubuntu linux station?

The only folders I see in my `android-sdk-linux` folder are the following:

```
add-ons
platforms
tools
```

I have not been able to find zipalign in any of these locations.

Answer (score 0):

its no longer included so you will need to copy it from an older version of the sdk into the tools folder